# I have a question regarding union type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I created my own type using numbers.
But, it didn't work.

This is the code for reproducing the issue.

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

type ANGLE = 0 | 90 | 180 | 270;

function test(angle: ANGLE) {
  console.log(angle)
}

test(_.shuffle([0, 90, 180, 270])[0])
```

But, I got an error.

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ANGLE'.`

I have no idea about this.
I thought it is not a problem because I used number both parameter type and argument type.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default an array literal of numbers is widened to `number` and the original number literal types are not preserved (so the types of the array elements are all converted to `number` basically)

You can use an `as const` assertion. This will make the compiler infer a readonly tuple from the array literal, and more importantly in this case, it will also preserver the array literal types:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

type ANGLE = 0 | 90 | 180 | 270;

function test(angle: ANGLE) {
  console.log(angle)
}

test(_.shuffle([0, 90, 180, 270] as const)[0])
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=21#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAfTgMyhEcDkAbCATAQwGcALTAbgChKYBPMAUzgEEA5AcQBkBROAXjgAGOAB84ATmFiAjAA4pcAEwB2QVUrIArgDsAxjGARtcGAyIwAFAW0BzbAwBcLDjwCUcAN6U4cXUaIQ9gB0uDZWtvaulAC+1KbmFghBpJrIyPYWANqCADQSuXByBSqCALpwxL7+MK7Zpa5AA)

Comment: Thank you so much! My custom type is the same as const type! I'd appreciate you for the explanation.